# Scala + Play: serialize Map to Json Array

Tags: json, scala, playframework

Imagine you have a Map[String, List[String]] that looks like this:

```
val myMap = Map(
   "ab" -> List("yo", "yo2", "yo3"),
   "cd" -> List("hi", "hi1", "hi2")
 )
```

if we do Json.toJson(myMap), the resulting JSON is

```
 {
   "ab" : ["yo", "yo2", "yo3"],
   "cd" : ["hi", "hi1", "hi2"]
 }
```

Is there a way we could get the outer container to be an array instead of an object? Like

```
 [
   "ab" : ["yo", "yo2", "yo3"],
   "cd" : ["hi", "hi1", "hi2"]
 ]
```

I'm not sure that this would be valid Json. Thanks.

Comment: No, that is not a valid Json. You can get an array of objects: [ { "ab": [] }, { "cd": [] }]. Is it what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last one is not valid JSON. You could use `Json.toJson(myMap.toList)` to obtain result as @Tyth has answered.
Actually `Map` is similar to `Object` of JSON format, cause it provides extracting values by key. In case with `Array`, it's reached over iterate over each element.